# use sharedpreference to the 15 most recent scores

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have an app that i use to do inspections on my business. i want to see the 15 most recent scores so i can see if we are getting better or worse. the way it should work would be that the newest one would go to the top and drop the oldest one each time a new one is submitted.

my sharedpreference class

```
public class SharedPreference {

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "AOP_PREFS";
    public static final String PREFS_KEY = "AOP_PREFS_String";

    public SharedPreference() {
        super();
    }

    public void save(Context context, String text) {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        Editor editor;

        //settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //1
        editor = settings.edit(); //2

        editor.putString(PREFS_KEY, text); //3

        editor.commit(); //4
    }

    public String getValue(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        String text;

        //settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        text = settings.getString(PREFS_KEY, null);
        return text;
    }

    public void clearSharedPreference(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        Editor editor;

        //settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = settings.edit();

        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void removeValue(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        Editor editor;

        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = settings.edit();

        editor.remove(PREFS_KEY);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

And my `View` it like this

```
public class past extends AppCompatActivity {

    // UI References
    private TextView textTxt;

    private String text;

    private SharedPreference sharedPreference;

    Activity context = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_past);

        sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();

        findViewsById();

        //Retrieve a value from SharedPreference
        text = sharedPreference.getValue(context);
        textTxt.setText(text);

    }

    private void findViewsById() {
        textTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scores);
    }

}
```

Right now all it shows is the most recent one and nothing else. how do i make it to where it will hold 15 strings???

Comment: Do you consider to use an SQLite database?

Comment: you cant do that to shared prefs because it does not behave like a ArrayList that can pop and push things

Comment: database would be ok but i don't know anything about sqlite, i still to new to that stuff. any tutorial or examples you know?

Comment: @JasonShulenberger may be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24358091/sqlite-or-sharedpreferences-for-high-scores?rq=1) could lead you some where!

Comment: store it as arraylist

Answer (score 0):

Use sqlite database, this is the simple implementation guide i can show, for more information search on google.

How your DB_helper looks, this is where you define the parameters ect.

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "yourDBname.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "yourtableName";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "FIRSTColumnName";
    public static final String COL_3 = "SECONDColumnName";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table "+ TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, FIRSTColumnName INTEGER,SECONDColumnName INTEGER)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+ TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }

    public boolean insertData(int FIRSTColumnName, int SECONDColumnName){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2,FIRSTColumnName);
        contentValues.put(COL_3,SECONDColumnName);
        long reuslt = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
        if (reuslt == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

then in your main app something like:

```
public void AddData(){

    gumb_poslji.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int seekBarProgressValue = seekBar.getProgress();//for example
            int seekBarProgressValue2 = seekBar2.getProgress();//for example
            String str1 = String.valueOf(seekBarProgressValue);
            String str2 = String.valueOf(seekBarProgressValue2);

            String data = str1;
            String data2 = str2;
           boolean check_of_entry = myDb.insertData(data ,data2);
            if (check_of_entry ==true)
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Try again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}
```

If you need any further assistance let me know.